# Sampling according to a normal distribution

Tags: sample

I have a given distance with a standard deviation. I have simulated now a few 100 distances and would like to draw from these distances a sample of 10-20 resembling the original distribution. Is there any standardized way of doing so?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. Could you try and reword your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want to draw 10-20 numbers from a normal distribution? In R, use `rnorm` function; for a generic solution, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution).

Comment: Thanks that got me on the right way and i was able to solve it!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question, because it doesn't "draw from these distances."  It's an independent sample from the same distribution, but it almost surely will have *no* numbers in common with the original "few 100 distances" you simulated.